# How to move Li inside an UL in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move registration link before login

```
<move element="register.link.container" destination="header.links" before="authorization-link"/>
```

but it's unable to move the register.link.container(li) before the authorization-link(li)

Comment: you can try destination "top.links" instead of  "header.links"

Comment: Hi naisa, i tried it before only but there is no luck.

Comment: finally got it.
          <move element="register.link.container" destination="header.links" before="authorization-link-login"/>